# How i can handle my socket

Tags: android, serversocket

Guys there is something wrong with my code when i run it gets connected to server and send the message but after that its stops. Any suggestions

```
 public void onClick(View arg0)
           {  serverIP=Ip.getText().toString();
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       try {
                           clientSocket= new Socket(serverIP,serverPort);//making the socket connection
                           printWriter=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                           String connect="connected to server";

                           printWriter.write(connect);
                           printWriter.flush();
                           printWriter.close();
                           clientSocket.close();


                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected to:"+serverIP+" on port:"+serverPort,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       catch(IOException e)
                       {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
               }).start();

           }
       });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNvxL.png)

Comment: If there's an error, that's going to be extremely useful information.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman i uploaded my logcat but i don't know how to make picture shown on the same page without link on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a Toast() call in the run() of a runnable.